# Error: inject() must be called from an injection context - Upgraded angular 8 to 9

Tags: angular, ivy

I upgraded my angular application from 8 to 9 with Ivy enabled. Now application is building correctly, but when I do ng serve I got an error in console -

```
Error: inject() must be called from an injection context
    at injectInjectorOnly (VM29 vendor.js:32922)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (VM29 vendor.js:32933)
    at Object.A11yModule_Factory [as factory] (VM29 vendor.js:8401)
    at R3Injector.push.../../node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm5/core.js.R3Injector.hydrate (VM29 vendor.js:195954)
    at R3Injector.push.../../node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm5/core.js.R3Injector.get (VM29 vendor.js:195771)
    at VM29 vendor.js:195809
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at R3Injector.push.../../node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm5/core.js.R3Injector._resolveInjectorDefTypes (VM29 vendor.js:195809)
    at new NgModuleRef$1 (VM29 vendor.js:209242)
    at NgModuleFactory.push.../../node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleFactory.create (VM29 vendor.js:209302)
```

Angular:

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.901.1",
"@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.901.1",
"@angular/cli": "^9.0.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.1",
```

Anyone has any idea?? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We noticed this problem recently, we hope this solution will help someone.

In our case, this problem occurred when importing a particular Angular library (custom).

The solution was to set `preserveSymlinks` to `true` in the `angular.json` file of the project that imported the library.

```
$.projects.<<PROJECT_NAME>>.architect.build.options.preserveSymlinks: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the root cause and what happened. I just deleted the workspace and git cloned the project again and this issue has gone. Strange!!